# Convert dictionary to custom json object c#

Tags: c#, json, dictionary

Here is something i couldn't get around my head even after spending a few hours. Hoping someone will direct me.

I have a `Dictionary` object which I want to convert to `JSON`.

Sample code:

```
Dictionary<String,String> users = new Dictionary<String,String>();
```

Users look something like this:

```
{[name1, department1],[name2, department2]}
```

Here is the custom JSON format for each user:

```
public class User
{
    public string name;
    public string dept;
    // has get and set methods for each.
}
```

How can I write the `users` Dictionary as a `JSON` object of type `user`?

Answer (score 3):

Ideally if the dictionary represents a collection of `user` objects then it in fact should *be* a collection of `user` objects.  But failing that, it can easily be transformed into one:

```
users.Select(u => new user { name = u.Key, dept = u.Value });
```

The resulting enumerable can then be serialized using pretty much any serializer.